# Read byte array up to a NUL character

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am receiving a packet with byte array via UDP in Java.
I know the maximum possible byte size, but I don't know currently received size.

If I create a String instance  from this byte array, then the string will have lots and lots of NUL characters  (\u0000) after the useful payload.

How do I convert this byte array  to String up to a point when the first NUL appears?
(I do not expect to have NUL in my payload).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create the `String` from the whole thing. Scan the *byte array* for the zero, and then call

```
new String(byteArray, 0, correctLength, "encoding")
```

Comment: Can I somehow avoid iterations? Or it won't consume much resources..?

Comment: A loop looking for zero bytes will take less time than just about anything else you are going to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use StringTokenizer to get the first part of the string until you see the first NULL.
something like: result = (new stringTokenizer(packet, null)).nextToken()

Answer (score 1):

`String` has a [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method that will break it into an array of strings based on where a regex appears. You could do

```
    s = s.split("\u0000")[0];
```

to split the string around NUL characters and take the first section.

Comment: But I don't really want to spend my resources on instantiating 95% useless string.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this recently, here's my solution:

```
public String getString(byte[] sb) {
    // trim nulls from end
    int strLen = sb.length;
    for (; strLen > 0; strLen--)
        if (sb[strLen - 1] != '\u0000')
            break;

    return new String(sb, 0, strLen, "UTF8");
}
```